# How to jump to tabbarcontroller from uiviewcontroller?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a ViewController as initial view controller and TabbarController. There are 3 buttons on view controller and TabbarController has 3 Tabs. 
I would like tapping the first button jump to first tab, second button - to the second Tab etc.
How should I do that? I'm working with storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Please Clarify your question if you just want to move your tab with click on button the use selectedatindex method for tab bar.

Comment: sorry for my english ) I would like to go to certain tab in TabBarController from ViewController

Answer (score 0):

try this,

step 1 ->import appDelegate class in your ViewController.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"

```
 - (IBAction) BtnOneClicked: (id) sender
 {
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
 }
- (IBAction) BtnTwoClicked: (id) sender 
 {
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
 }
- (IBAction) BtnThreeClicked: (id) sender 
{
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
}
```

Comment: no action, unfortunately
may be I have mistakes in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: simple create tabbar application in your xcode and create 3 buttons in your firstViewController put it above code

Comment: no! ViewController must be before TabBarController
here http://dfiles.ru/files/cqsc8h5hz you can see what I want to do )

Comment: Thank you, but i'm using Storyboards without XIB... being new in Xcode a have difficulties to use your example with Storyboards

Answer (score 0):

A normal View Controller Button Click Event We can jump On Tab bar Controller as simple as Normal just Crete a `cocoatouch` class which will we sub class of `UitabBarController` and present to the View.

```
 @IBAction func goActivityView(_ sender: Any) {

   let gotoActivityView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController


  self.present(gotoActivityView, animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
```